# fetch value of a Widget in an activity from another Java file in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How should I fetch value of a `Checkbox` which is in an `Activity` and in its `onCreate` there is `findviewbyId` method.

```
public class abc extends Activity {
Checkbox mon;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_xml);
            mon = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_mon);
    }
    public boolean check()
    {
    if (mon.isChecked())
    return true;
    else
    return false;
    }}
```

Now, there is another java class, in which I am passing the activity class object and calling that method which returns the value.

```
abc a =new abc();
a.check();
```

But it is not working. I think there is problem with `findviewbyid` statement. 
And also, if the acitivity is not being opened , I want it to show the defualt value which I set in the xml file

```
android:checked="false"
```

Comment: `abc a =new abc();` mean creating a new object which has no link with original running activity

Comment: if i am not running the acitivity and still want to fetch that checkbox's value (expecting to get the default value) 
how am i supposed to do that from another file? :(

Comment: if the activity is not running then isn't it obvious that the value will be `false`

Comment: send the value using intent to another class, if u starting an activity.

Comment: @W4R10CK can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: @UrviG, check my answer i posted

Comment: If the activity is not running and you do not get to this *other file* from the activity you should save the value in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Set a static variable and assign the value of `CheckBox`:

```
public class abc extends Activity {
Checkbox mon;
public static boolean checkBoxValue; //here

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_xml);
        mon = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_mon);
}
public boolean check()
{
if (mon.isChecked())
checkBoxValue = true; //here
return true;
else
checkBoxValue = false;  //here
}}
```

Another class:

```
public class AnotherClass {
  .....

  public boolean value = abc.checkBoxValue;
  .......

}
```

**Another way**

abc Activity:

```
public boolean check()
{
if (mon.isChecked())
Intent intent = new Intent(this, anotherClass.class);
intent.putExtra("value", true);
startActivity(intent); 
return true;
.....
   .......
```

another Activty:

```
public class AnotherClass extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anotherclass);

    boolean value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("value");

  }
}
```

Comment: This will not call the function and hence, the value of the variable wont be updated..

Comment: @UrviG, I didn't the point _This will not call the function_ ?

Comment: @UrviG, I got the point of yours. First check the value of view in the main java class and pass the value to another. Calling the view status is not possible in another class(may be constructor is passed).

Answer (score 0):

Boolean with static modifier would be enough for your case.

```
public static boolean monValue = false // as you mention the default is false
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.my_xml);
  mon = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_mon);
  mon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean b) {
      monValue = b;
    }
  });
}
```

Then you just need to `boolean x = abc.monValue` in other class.
But I really want to suggest another way to communicate between class within android lifecycle.

---

With [**EventBus**](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Create class that wraps event data

```
public class MyCheckboxEvent {
  public final boolean checked;

  public MyCheckboxEvent(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
  }
}
```

Then add `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyCheckboxEvent(booleanValue));` on you abc activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.my_xml);
  mon = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_mon);
  mon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean b) {
      EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyCheckboxEvent(b));
    }
  });
}
```

Add the handler on any class that subscribe the `abc` Checkbox event data

```
@Subscribe
public void handleMyAbcCheckbox(MyCheckboxEvent event) {
  boolean x = event.checked;
}
```

Then register and unregister the subscriber according to the lifecycle

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```